# Mark buttons with unique ID and identify this ID value upon button clicked

Tags: php, javascript, button

We have html site based on php+mysql. On a page, there is table (4 rows and 1 column) having information about users. Each table cell has user name and appropriate button under it. User names populated to table using SELECT statement.

```
$q = "select usr.user_id, usr.nickname from users usr";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Then info get's populated into table

```
echo "<table border cellpadding=1>"; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nickname'] . "</td> <form name ='form_type' method ='GET'><input type = 'button' name = " . $row['user_id'] . " value = 'ButtonValue' id = 'ButtonId'  onclick='processFormData();'></form></td>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
```

Javascript for getting ButtonName

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function processFormData() {
        var name_element = document.getElementById('ButtonId');
        alert(name_element.name);
    }
```

Alert is using for testing.
My aim is to get user_id value upon button clicked. Currently I'm getting same user_id (firstly found) for all buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    echo "<td>" . $row['nickname'] . "</td> <form name ='form_type' method ='GET'><input type = 'button' name = " . $row['user_id'] . " value = 'ButtonValue' id = 'ButtonId'  onclick='processFormData(this);'></form></td>";
```

And this:

```
function processFormData(name_element) {
    alert(name_element.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for response. It works just fine, but I've faced another problem. Upon button clicked i have to invoke specific UPDATE statement which will use $row['user_id'] variable as argument. Is it possible to do this with solution above (pass variable to JS)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `User ID` to `JavaScript` function like this,

```
<input type = 'button' name = " . $row['user_id'] . " value = 'ButtonValue' id = 'ButtonId'  onclick='processFormData('<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>');'>
```

In `Script`, you have to change the function link this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function processFormData(uid) {
    alert(uid);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This still won't work, since `this.value` is always `ButtonValue`.

Comment: Please check the edited answer... it should work... You have to pass userid as an argument in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The id of `ButtonID` is on every button.  This means none of them are unique.  So, your script starts looking, and gives the same one every time.

You could just switch the `name` and `id` attributes (you'll need some text so the ID isn't just a number, that's not allowed):

```
<input type='button' id='btn".$row['user_id']."' value='ButtonValue' name='ButtonId'  onclick='processFormData();'>
```

and then alert the (new, unique) ID:

```
alert(name_element.id);
```

But now since your ID has changed, your Javascript code won't find `ButtonId` anymore.  So, you'll need to pass the button object to the Javascript directly.  It could look like this:

HTML

```
<input type='button' id='btn".$row['user_id']."' value='ButtonValue'  onclick='processFormData(this);'>
```

JS

```
function processFormData(element) {
    alert(element.id);
}
```